# What is the regular expression in notepad++ to detect words like '%NPN%' that end with crlf character?

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, newline

hi 
What is the regular expression in notepad++ to detect words like '%NPN%' that end with crlf character?

for exampple : 02NPNFLUDE - 12NPNGPDSA and etc

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually

```
\w*NPN\w*$
```

matches a word containing the letters `NPN` and consisting of alphanumeric characters, only if it is at the end of a line (`$` matches the end of the line, which is of course right before a CRLF).

I'm not sure if Notepad++ does support the `\w` shorthand, though. If this doesn't work, try

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]*NPN[A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

but be aware that only ASCII letters and digits will now match, no accented characters. If that's not a problem, fine.

Comment: Tim, Thank you for your attention. But unfortunately, it did not work.  Actually, What I did was: After clicking CTRL+F to appear Find windows I copied what you had postd to me but it did not detect them..... What's wrong?

Comment: I don't have Notepad++, but in all the editors I know, you have to check an option that you want to use regular expressions for the search. If this doesn't help, please edit your question and add a sample from the actual file you're trying to match. Paste it into the editor, mark it, and press Ctrl-K to format it as verbatim text.

Comment: Oh Tim, It was my fault. Sorry. I Changed what you has posted into [A-Za-z0-9]*(NPN)[A-Za-z]*$ and it worked. :)  Now, I saw that Notepad++ has an option named "Macro" . Actually I wanna to detect words like 02NPNFLUDE or 12NPNGPDSA that are at the end of a line right before a CRLF and then delete CRLF and put 2 spaces after them. How Can I create a macro to do it automatically for every file I open with Notepad++ ?    Thanks

Comment: That's the problem with Notepad++: As far as I know, you can't match newlines with standard regular expressions (but check out darioo's answer!). I suggest you cough up the cash for a fully regex-capable editor like EditPadPro (or, with some limits, UltraEdit) and you're good to go.

Comment: As of version 6.6.8, the \w works to find all alphanum values.

In the case above the following would match the entire line (ensure to click the radiobutton for Regular Expression and the checkbox for ". matches newline"):
"[\w -]+NPN[ -\w]+."  (Replace the + with * if you expect NPN to start or end a line)

Comment: \w worked wonders for me, though for some reason it wouldn't work if I used multiple \w in the "Find what: " box.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ regular expressions don't know how to handle newline characters like `\r` or `\n`. This is a limitation of the [Scintilla editing component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintilla_%28editing_component%29) it uses.

You'll have to use extended search mode. More explanation about everything I said can be found [here](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html).